# Disk on key is read only on every computer

Tags: linux, disk, readonly

I have a 16 GB SanDisk Cruzer Blade Disk-on-key.

After a few days of use, it has become write-protected/read-only.

When I plug it in, you can see this in my Ubuntu's `dmesg`:

```
[  819.003359] usb 2-5: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  819.136249] usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5567
[  819.136257] usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  819.136261] usb 2-5: Product: Cruzer Blade
[  819.136265] usb 2-5: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[  819.136269] usb 2-5: SerialNumber: 4C530210071007116494
[  819.136891] usb-storage 2-5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  819.137024] scsi8 : usb-storage 2-5:1.0
[  820.136696] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Blade   2.01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  820.137150] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  820.138497] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] 31266816 512-byte logical blocks: (16.0 GB/14.9 GiB)
[  820.142194] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is on
[  820.142204] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 80 00
[  820.144629] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  820.156667]  sdc: sdc1
[  820.159903] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

You can see that is says that write-protect is on.

I've already tried:

- Looking for a read-only hardware switch
- Using Gparted to format the drive. It says that the drive is read-only so it can't write to it
- Using dd to overwrite the drive with 0s. It also can't open the device (`/dev/sdc`) for writing.
- Pluging it in to a Windows 7. It too says it's read only

I did find [this](http://forums.sandisk.com/t5/All-SanDisk-USB-Flash-Drives/SanDisk-Cruzer-Blade-16GB-write-protected-error/td-p/253484) thread on Sandisk's forums.
Does it mean that this has no solution? Must I just throw the Disk on Key after a mere days of use?

Answer (score 11):

I've contacted SanDisk, and they've said it happened "beacuse the flash drive has detected a potential fault and became write-protected to prevent data loss. There is no method to fix this."

They've offered to replace it if I send it to them on my own expense.

They are, as it turns out, aware of this problem.

I, however, chose to switch to another company's disk-on-key.

Thank you.

Comment: Got the same issue with SanDisk Ultra USB 3.0 16GB,
(idVendor=0781, idProduct=5581, SerialNumber: A20042D67501C440)

Comment: Sandisk's Flash memories seem to be really, really faulty. A similar issue happened to me with a 64 GB Sandisk Micro SD card, only in this case the SD card did report the writes as successful but internally it would just discard them. I luckily found out because I moved a bunch of random downloaded crud into my SD card only to end up not seeing it at all, luckily because I didn't find out after losing a bunch of prized pictures due to a botched move operation.

Answer (score 3):

> [ 820.142194] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is on

At least some flash storage devices (such as SD cards) do have internal write protect settings, including a *permanent* write protect bit.  I first heard of this **[here](http://hackaday.com/2013/11/12/keep-your-sd-cards-data-safe-with-the-sd-locker/)**, and don't know if it could apply to your device, but if you could not `dd` *with root privileges* to a USB stick then it would seem to be a hardware lock.

However, if this was done intentionally by, e.g., some Windows safety mechanism, it's unlikely that would use the permanent bit (if any).

Try:

```
sudo hdparm -r /dev/sdN
```

Where `sdN` is the correct device node.  You will probably get:

```
/dev/sda:
readonly      =  1 (on)
```

Note that you may have to install `hdparm` first (search for a package with that in the name).  You can try to change this setting with:

```
sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdN
```

This should set the "readonly" option to `0 (off)`.  For more details consult `man hdparm`.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried using hdparm. Checking the write-protect bit does say that is is on. Setting it seems like it succeeded, but it is still write-protected and removing and re-plugging the disk-on-key makes that bit to return to 'on'

Comment: Hmph.  Well, the thing I certainly *don't* recommend bothering with is buying another one, lol.  19 pages of posts about this on Sandisk's own forum -- with no final solution except "it is probably broken except there's no way to prove this as Sandisk do not give their factory tools out to the public" probably == you got burned. :(

Comment: OTOH if you can *return* it for another one, Sandisk has probably made millions of these, and it could be some small percentage of them pass a QA check but then break within days.  Your chances of having it happen twice in a row are probably really slim -- they do have a brand name to protect.

Comment: `hdparm` only controls the kernel read only setting for a drive, not any hardware setting it may have.

Comment: @psusi Foiled again. If it does involve hardware switches, this probably then requires Sandisk drivers which auto-installed via windows but are non-existent for linux, so looking for windows tools to reset this if possible is the best bet.  Or it's just defective -- since we don't have a survey of all users of the device it is impossible to say whether it is a common problem or 1 in 100,000, etc.

Comment: It's an interesting command but it didn't have any effect